# what is typeof((c) + 1) in C

Tags: c, gcc

I came across an expression in C like

```
typeof((c) + 1) _tmp = c;
```

What exactly does this mean?

Thanks for the reply.

Just one doubt? What if the type of c is struct instead of the primitive types, then what will +1 do?

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html

Comment: really nice question! I learned something new today

Comment: @SiegeX - Probably as `#define MACRO(..., c, ...)`

Answer (score 57):

The `typeof` operator in plain C (not C++) is a GCC addition to the standard. It tells the compiler you want to use the type of the expression enclosed in parenthesis.

Using `typeof` as above, you can declare variables of types unknown to you or in that context, using another variable's type as reference. It can also be used for casting.

The `+` operation inside `typeof` has a peculiar effect. `typeof((c) + 1)` means *"the type of c, or the type of 1, whichever would remain after promotion"*. Remember that, for example, chars are promoted to ints when used in operations involving ints, ints are promoted to floats, floats to doubles, etc.

So, `typeof(int_variable + char_variable)` is `int`, since the `char` would be promoted to `int` to perform the operation.

Note that only the compiler can resolve this: `typeof` doesn't evaluate, it has no value, nothing happens at run-time.

The full description of `typeof` can be [found here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html).

Comment: @Santiago Lezica:what is the `type of 1`? Sorry I did not get that

Comment: @user* hmm let's say that when you write `1` in your code, the compiler assumes that's an integer with value 1. The type of `1` is `int`.

Comment: @Santiago Lezica:So it is compiler specific what is the type?

Comment: @user* well, you can safely bet it'll be `int` mostly anywhere, but as I said, `typeof` is a GNU C Compiler (GCC) feature anyway, it's not standard in C.

Comment: What if the type of c here is a struct, then what will + 1 do??

Comment: @zombie - Probably a compile-time error, which is probably the expected usage when you try to use number functions (which I assume this is meant to be) on `struct`s.

Comment: If `c` is an array of type `T`, the expression `(c) + 1` is of type pointer to `T`, so the "+1" could have another use: to get a pointer type.  `int c[4]; typeof(c+1) a; a = c;` for example.

Comment: "typeof doesn't evaluate, it has no value, nothing happens at run-time." Unfortunately, this is not 100% true, there is special case where something happens at runtime, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11504630/396730

Comment: Woa, would've never guessed that. But come on, `typeof(int[++x])` ? You're just asking for things to break there haha

Answer (score 5):

create var `_tmp` st `_tmp` is of type upcast (max) of `c` or `int` and set it to value  of `c`.

eg

```
char c -> int _tmp // char(c) + 1 is int
float c -> float _tmp // float(c) + 1 is float
```

Comment: What will +1 do? I understand the use of typeof, but fail to understand what will + 1 in typeof do

Comment: @zom force tmp to become int if `c` is "smaller" then int

Comment: Where does the `+1` come into play?

Comment: @Stilgar is that due to integer promotion?

Comment: In brief: yes, it is due to integer promotion.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answer, the `+` here is quite subtle. It allows for `c` to be either an expression or a type.

- If it is an expression then, as said,
  `c` is promoted to `int` (at least)
  and the type of the whole expression
  has at least integer rank of `int`.
- If it is a type expression the
  parenthesis surrounding `c` make it a
  cast of the value `+1`. So then the resulting type is just `c`.

For both kinds of acrobatic it is important that `c` is of arithmetic type and it is also to note that this trick here might loose the signedness of `c`. So this use of the `typeof` extension is not so useful as it might look like. In most cases using `uintmax_t` or `intmax_t` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

It is not standard C. C has no such thing as `typeof` (unless you are dealing with something user-defined).

`typeof` is normally a compiler extension (GCC compiler most likely). You can read about it here

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html

Comment: This really doesn't explain what the `+1` is doing

Comment: @SiegeX: This also doesn't explain what `=` is doing and what `;` is doing. When such a broad question as "what's it doing?" is asked, it is up to the person making the answer to decide what to say and what not to say. I decided that the above is sufficient.

Comment: congrats on your decision. However, I, and many others (look at other comments on other answers) felt an explanation of what the `+1` was doing was in order as it is not intuitive within the scope of `typeof`.

Answer (score 4):

Compare the code,

```
typeof((c) + 1) _tmp = c;
```

with

```
typeof(c) _tmp = c;
```

`typeof` allows arguments of types or variables.  Now consider `c` as,

- `struct { int a; int b }`
- a pointer to `struct { int a; int b }`
- the actual text `int`.

As well as *promoting* `char`<sup>as per [uʍop ǝpısdn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/469300/uwop-episdn)</sup>, the macro protects against a `struct` assignment.  So the following code will not compile,

```
struct { int a; int b } c;
typeof((c)+1) _tmp = c;
```

People may wish to forbid `struct` assignments for efficiency and code size reasons, especially with-in a generic macro.

Answer (score 1):

Typeof returns a type, and is evaluated at compile time.

The whole statement means declare a variable `tmp` with the same type as c (usually).

It might declare a related or different type, since the type of c+1 can be different to c.  (this is more likely in c++).

Comment: Even in C, if `c` is `char` or `short` and `int` is bigger then the type of the expression `c+1` will by `int`. If `c` is a larger integral type or is a `float` or `double`, then the type of the expression is the type of `c`. It doesn't require C++ to get some confusion about types...

Comment: What if the type of c here is a struct, then what will + 1 do??

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, only for pointer, `typeof((c) + 1) = typeof(c);` so this maybe assure the passing parameter is pointer