# Side effects within a typeof() expression

Tags: c, gcc

In GNUC C, you can use `typeof(expression)`, and it is legal to use an expression with side effects inside. So for example you can have this C code:

```
int x = 0;
typeof(x++) y;
```

In this case, the side effect is ignored and x is still zero afterwards (this makes sense as types are a compile-time-only thing).

However, the [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) says:

> The operand of typeof is evaluated for its side effects
>   if and only if it is an expression of variably modified type
>   or the name of such a type.

What does this sentence mean? Is it really possible to write `typeof` with a side effect and have the side effect actually be executed at runtime? For me, this sentence seems to indicate this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4436889/195488

Comment: @0A0D That question also talks about `typeof`, but does not mention side effects, only side-effect-free expressions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is possible in certain cases to have side-effects inside `typeof` evaluated. As the documentation says, it needs to be within a "variably modified type". This is a type which depends on some runtime value, such as `int[x]`.

So the following code is legal, declares y to be of type `int[1]`, and x has the value 1 afterwards:

```
int x = 0;
typeof(int[++x]) y;
```

Of course, equally to variably modified types in general, this is only legal for local variable declarations (inside function).

Comment: Note that this is the same as for `sizeof`: the expression operand is not evaluated except if a variable length array appears and the value of the array size affects the result of the `sizeof` expression.