# What is 'typeof((fifo) + 1)' means from linux/kfifo.h file?

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel

I found the below code from linux/kfifo.h file in Linux kernel source.

```
/**
 * kfifo_init - initialize a fifo using a preallocated buffer
 * @fifo: the fifo to assign the buffer
 * @buffer: the preallocated buffer to be used
 * @size: the size of the internal buffer, this have to be a power of 2
 *
 * This macro initialize a fifo using a preallocated buffer.
 *
 * The numer of elements will be rounded-up to a power of 2.
 * Return 0 if no error, otherwise an error code.
 */
#define kfifo_init(fifo, buffer, size) \
({ \
    typeof((fifo) + 1) __tmp = (fifo); \
    struct __kfifo *__kfifo = &__tmp->kfifo; \
    __is_kfifo_ptr(__tmp) ? \
    __kfifo_init(__kfifo, buffer, size, sizeof(*__tmp->type)) : \
    -EINVAL; \
})
```

From this code, what is the meaning of "typeof((fifo) + 1)" ? 
Why not using 'typeof(fifo) __tmpl = (fifo);'

Comment: OK. After spending 5 minutes more, I can understand why. kfifo_init and other kfifo related macros needs the 1st argument as pointer to kfifo struct. if users of this macro accidentally used plain kfifo struct to 1st argument, this will make compilation error because of + 1 in typeof.

Comment: I was also curious.  The '+1' tells gcc to take the type of '1' (int) or the type of 'fifo', whichever would need to get promoted.  Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436889/what-is-typeofc-1-in-c

Comment: Interesting, @PeterL. link's explain is totally different then I thought. need to think about it more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@WonilYour first assumption is correct. This construct is used to check if a pointer was used as argument.

When a plain struct is given, the expression will raise a compiler error, because a struct is used in a unary + with an int.

When a pointer is given, the binary + will add 1 to it which will still be a pointer to the same type and the expression is syntactically right.

Comment: I had guessed that the reason was something along these lines. This kind of trick is useful, but I kind of wish there were a remark about it in the header file since it's not obvious what the intent is.